# Can I incorporate if, else statements with input?

Tags: python, validation, if-statement, input

I am practicing and learning Python, and I had this idea to incorporate if, else statements with input, but it didn't work. So, I tried break, continue and except commands.

```
name = input("Hello! What's your name?" )
print("Hello," + name + "!")
age = int(input("How old are you? "))
while age <= 13 or age >= 55:
    if age < 13:
        print("You are too young!")
        continue  
    if age >= 55:
        print("You are too old!")
        continue
    else:
        print("Welcome!")
        continue
why = input("Why are you here? ")
print("Welcome!")
```

So, I was trying to go when a person who is over 55 or under 13, it'll boot them out of the input. But, when I tried it, it just printed the print on and on, infinitely.

```
name = input("Hello! What's your name?" )
print("Hello," + name + "!")
age = int(input("How old are you? "))
while age <= 13 or age >= 55:
    if age < 13:
        print("You are too young!")
        break  
     if age >= 55:
        print("You are too old!")
        break
    else:
        print("Welcome!")
        continue
why = input("Why are you here? ")
print("Welcome!")
```

Here is another one, I tried tweaking it. But what happened is I tried doing break. It did the print but just moved on with the command.

Can someone give me a explanation on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

I can spot two main issues

1. You should replace the second `if` with an `elif` statement
2. The last two lines aren't indented

For the first problem, both `if` statements will likely run

```py
age = 12
if age < 13: # This is true
    print("You are too young!")
    break  
if age >= 55: # This is false
    print("You are too old!")
    break
else: # But this will also run
    print("Welcome!")
    continue
```

You can fix this by replacing it with an `elif`

```py
age = 12
if age < 13: # This is true
    print("You are too young!")
    break  
elif age >= 55: # This won't run
    print("You are too old!")
    break
else: # This also won't run
    print("Welcome!")
    continue
```

(I should note that, because of the `break` statements in each `if`, the code never reaches the second if statement.)

The second issue comes from the fact that Python puts a large emphasis on tabs.
For example,

```py
while True:
    print("Hello")
print("World!") # Un-indented code means it's not part of the `while` loop
```

Will only print `Hello` over and over again. Meanwhile,

```py
while True:
    print("Hello")
    print("World!")
```

Will print `Hello World!` forever.
Indenting the last two lines by a single tab will put the statements into the `while` loop, which should fix your problem. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation of continue and break**

So `continue` is used in loops and will go to the next iteration of the loop (skipping over any other instructions that you have below the `continue` keyword). Here you are using a `while` loop, as you don't have any condition that updates the value of `age` the loop will continue to repeat (infinite) because there is no update to make the condition (`age <= 13 or age >= 55`) false to terminate the loop.

`break` on the other hand is used to stop further iterations in a loop.

**suggestions**

your `while` loop is necessary because you are only ever checking the `age` value once.

would suggest using @Steggy's recommendation

```
if age < 13: # This is true
    print("You are too young!")
    break  
elif age >= 55: # This won't run
    print("You are too old!")
    break
else: # This also won't run
    print("Welcome!")
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

debugging your 2nd code.

User input **age value less than 13**: It will print the statement `too young` and `break` statement will help to exit the `while` loop

User input **age value equal to 13**: first and second if block not satisfy the condition hence it will run else block it will print welcome and by doing `continue` **you move to the next iteration of while loop**. hence again and again this else block run and your while loop **tend to infinity** reason **your age value is fixed**. solution you can take the age input inside the else block so that user input again or you can use **break** as you used in first two if's

User input **age value greater than or equal to 55**: It will run second if block and break statement helps to terminate while loop.

**Also if your age is fixed i don't think the while loop is necessary you can directly** do `if elif..`

If your age is not fixed. than you should take input inside the while loop.

```
while True:
    # This will take input until age input is less than 13 or age is greater than or equal to 55.
    age = int(input("How old are you? ")) 
    if age < 13:
        print("You are too young!")
        break  
    elif age >= 55:
        print("You are too old!")
        break
```